# Why can't I assign a *Struct to an *Interface?

Tags: go

I'm just working through the [Go tour](http://tour.golang.org/), and I'm confused about pointers and interfaces. Why doesn't this Go code compile?

```
package main

type Interface interface {}

type Struct struct {}

func main() {
    var ps *Struct
    var pi *Interface
    pi = ps

    _, _ = pi, ps
}
```

i.e. if `Struct` is an `Interface`, why wouldn't a `*Struct` be a `*Interface`?

The error message I get is:

```
prog.go:10: cannot use ps (type *Struct) as type *Interface in assignment:
        *Interface is pointer to interface, not interface
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20874798/260805

Comment: it looks like the interfaces could behaves like implicit pointers...

Comment: may i suggest to enrich your playground with `func main() {
 var ps *Struct = new(Struct)
 var pi *Interface
 var i Interface
 i = ps
 pi = &i
 fmt.Printf("%v, %v, %v\n", *ps, pi, &i)
 i = *ps
 fmt.Printf("%v, %v, %v\n", *ps, pi, i)

 _, _, _ = i, pi, ps
}` and make your own conclussions

Answer (score 226, accepted):

When you have a struct implementing an interface, a pointer to that struct implements automatically that interface too. That's why you never have `*SomeInterface` in the prototype of functions, as this wouldn't add anything to `SomeInterface`, and you don't need such a type in variable declaration (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255907/in-go-http-handlers-why-is-the-responsewriter-a-value-but-the-request-a-pointer)).

An interface value isn't the value of the concrete struct (as it has a variable size, this wouldn't be possible), but it's a kind of pointer (to be more precise a pointer to the struct and a pointer to the type). Russ Cox describes it exactly [here](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces) :

> Interface values are represented as a two-word pair giving a pointer
>   to information about the type stored in the interface and a pointer to
>   the associated data.

[image]

This is why `Interface`, and not `*Interface` is the correct type to hold a pointer to a struct implementing `Interface`.

So you must simply use

```
var pi Interface
```

Comment: OK, I think that makes sense to me. I'm just wondering why (in that case), it's not simply a compile time error to say `var pi *Interface`.

Comment: I went into more details to explain it. See edit. I suggest the reading of the Russ Cox's article I link to.

Comment: @SimonNickerson: pointers to different types are not interchangeable. If they were, you could use the interface pointer to overwrite the thing pointed to with any value of any type that implements the interface, which is obviously not good

Comment: This just helped me make sense of pointers in a way I was *never* able to do in C or C++ ... thank you so much for this elegant and simple explanation :-)

Comment: Alright, I still don't get why `*SomeInterface` isn't simply a compile error?

Comment: thanks for the explanation... although i don't get what is the "prototype of functions"?

Comment: @charneykaye You are not entirely correct here. You never have *SomeInterface **when declaring an interface variable** or **when returning an interface type as part of a function declaration**. However **you can have *SomeInterface within a function's parameters**.

Comment: so tecnically interface{} is a **wrapper** (i guess we should use that word for transmiting the idea at a glance..., humble suggestion folks)

Comment: Turns out that hiding the pointer was not such a hot language design idea after all, as you still need to be aware it exists, just like it exists in slices and maps.

Answer (score 10):

This is perhaps what you meant:

```
package main

type Interface interface{}

type Struct struct{}

func main() {
        var ps *Struct
        var pi *Interface
        pi = new(Interface)
        *pi = ps

        _, _ = pi, ps
}
```

Compiles OK. See also [here](http://play.golang.org/p/9etOGTAzua).

Comment: This should be accepted, the other doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple way of assigning a struct to an interface:

```
package main

type Interface interface{}

type Struct struct{}

func main() {
    ps := new(Struct)
    pi := Interface(ps)

    _, _ = pi, ps
}
```

**https://play.golang.org/p/BRTaTA5AG0S**

Answer (score 0):

Im using the following way of `interface{}` while im just consuming `eventsI interface{}` as arguments, im still able to send a Struct Pointers as you can see below.

```
func Wait(seconds float64) *WaitEvent {
    return WaitEventCreate(seconds)
}
```

main.go

```
var introScene = []interface{}{
        storyboard.Wait(5),
        storyboard.Wait(2),
    }

    var storyboardI = storyboard.Create(stack, introScene)
    stack.Push(&storyboardI)
```

Now inside `storyboard.go` file Create function

```
type Storyboard struct {
    Stack  *gui.StateStack
    Events []interface{} //always keep as last args
}

func Create(stack *gui.StateStack, eventsI interface{}) Storyboard {
    sb := Storyboard{
        Stack: stack,
    }

    if eventsI != nil {
        events := reflect.ValueOf(eventsI)
        if events.Len() > 0 {
            sb.Events = make([]interface{}, events.Len())
            for i := 0; i < events.Len(); i++ {
                sb.Events[i] = events.Index(i).Interface()
            }
        }
    }

    return sb
}
```

As you can see above the Storyboard.go is consuming just `Events []interface{}` but in-fact Im sending is a Struct pointer and it works fine.

another more example [here](https://dev.to/steelx/state-machine-in-go-for-a-2d-game-198l)