# Pass struct for function that accepts a interface

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
package main


type MyInterface interface {
    Test()
}

type MyType struct {

}
func (m MyType) Test(){}

func AcceptInterface(i *MyInterface){
}

func main() {

    object := &MyType{}
    AcceptInterface(object)
}
```

I was expecting this to work, because MyType implements MyInterface, but I get:

> cannot use object (type *MyType) as type *MyInterface in argument to
>   AcceptInterface:  *MyInterface is pointer to interface, not interface

I tried doing type assertion: object.(MyInterface), but that doesn't work either.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You never need a pointer to an interface. Just remove the pointer from the type.

Comment: adding to what @JimB said this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511203/why-cant-i-assign-a-struct-to-an-interface

Comment: Why the downvote? I know it's a newbie mistake, but there's no place in SO for beginners?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the error says,

> cannot use object (type *MyType) as type *MyInterface in argument to AcceptInterface: *MyInterface is pointer to interface, not interface

This means that it is expecting an `interface` value, not a pointer.

If you change the pointers to values in your code (by removing the `&` and `*`), the program will run with no errors:

```
package main


type MyInterface interface {
    Test()
}

type MyType struct {

}
func (m MyType) Test(){}

func AcceptInterface(i MyInterface){
}

func main() {

    object := MyType{}
    AcceptInterface(object)
}
```

[Play it](https://play.golang.org/p/8ONqtYO1jT)

#### Edit 1

If you still want to use a pointer as an argument, there are two important parts of the Go language to note

1. From the [Go Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) on what *exacly* is a variable that fits an instance:

   > A variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method set that is any superset of the interface.
2. From the [Go Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) on what pointers being automatically dereferenced:

   > As with selectors, a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: `pt.Mv` is equivalent to `(*pt).Mv` [and] as with method calls, a reference to a non-interface method with a pointer receiver using an addressable value will automatically take the address of that value: `t.Mp` is equivalent to `(&t).Mp.`

Those two points are important, because when combined they explain that *pointers to variables can still fit instances*. This is because the pointer's [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) is automatically dereferenced by the Go compiler *(and since the variable it is referencing can fit an instance, the pointer can, too)*!

In action, this means that in order to see if a pointer fits an instance, you have to declare the instance as a *value* and the pointer as a *pointer*.

If you run this code:

```
package main

type MyInterface interface {
    Test()
}

type MyType struct {
}

func (m MyType) Test() {}

func AcceptInterface(i MyInterface) {
}

func main() {
    object := &MyType{}
    AcceptInterface(object)
}
```

[Play it](https://play.golang.org/p/xJjAShDJMv)

you will see that there are no errors! Notice how there *is* an `&` in the `object` declaration, but *no `*`* in the `i` declaration?

Comment: That works, thanks! But I don't quite understand why I can't pass pointers, does that means that interfaces are "first class citizens", I can have pointers to actual interfaces instead of a struct? Don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @lucaswxp I edited my answer with a way to pass in pointers; hopefully it helps you!

Comment: @lucaswxp The main issue in your code, as also pointed by @JimB, is that your `AcceptInterface` expects *pointer* to an interface argument. In general, you should just use interface argument. If it's fixed, you can pass struct pointers into it.

Comment: I think the more interesting question (to me) is why we cannot have an interface pointer as a parameter? What does an interface pointer mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyInterface interface {
    Test()
}

type MyType struct {

}
func (m MyType) Test(){}
```

**Note**: it means that `MyType` implemts the interface `MyInterface`, not `MyType*`.

You can use:

```
func (m *MyType) Test(){}  //Notice here

func AcceptInterface(i *MyInterface){
}

func main() {

    object := &MyType{}
    AcceptInterface(object)
}
```

Comment: From the spec: `The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T`. You can use a pointer or struct value interchangeably with a value receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit typing if you want to pass a pointer to interface:

```
func main() {
    var object MyInterface = MyType{}
    AcceptInterface(&object)
}
```

I would not recommend using pointer interfaces as you would need to write code like `(*i).Test()` to call the interface pointer methods. The compiler do auto dereferencing for struct pointers, not so for interface pointers.