# Slice of pointers, when passed to object, gets pointers with other addresses

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface, polymorphism

I'm trying to pass a slice of pointers to structs that implement the interface LogicAdapter. Here's my code:

**main.go:**

```
var adapters[]LogicAdapter
    adapter1 := &ExampleAdapter{}
    fmt.Printf("Addr: %p\n", adapter1)
    adapters = append(adapters, adapter1)
    bot := ChatterBot{"Charlie", MultiLogicAdapter{adapters}}
    bot.getResponse("test", 0)
```

**multiadapterlogic.go:**

```
type MultiLogicAdapter struct {
    adapters []LogicAdapter
}

func (logic *MultiLogicAdapter) process(text string, session int) string {
    //response := logic.adapters[0].process(text, session)
    response := ""
    for _, adapter := range logic.adapters {
        fmt.Printf("Addr: %p\n", &adapter)
    }
    _ = response
    return ""
}
```

The output of main is:

```
Addr: 0x5178f0

Addr: 0xc42000a340
```

I didn't include LogicAdapter because I don't think it's necessary. 
I don't like to fill this with much code, but here's ChatterBot if it makes things easier to understand (but keep in mind that `bot.getResponse` calls `process`, that's it)

**chatterbot.go**

```
type ChatterBot struct {
    Name string
    MultiLogicAdapter
}

func (bot *ChatterBot) getResponse(text string, session int) string {
    response := bot.process(text, session)
    _ = response
    return ""
}
```

First of all, I had the idea of storing pointers to LogicAdapters, in this way

```
var adapters[]*LogicAdapter
```

but everytime I tried to insert the adapter1 pointer there, I got:

*LogicAdapter is pointer to interface, not interface

so I discovered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511203/why-cant-i-assign-a-struct-to-an-interface) and learned this:

> When you have a struct implementing an interface, a pointer to that
>   struct implements automatically that interface too. That's why you
>   never have *SomeInterface in the prototype of functions, as this
>   wouldn't add anything to SomeInterface, and you don't need such a type
>   in variable declaration (see this related question).

So I decided to leave the `adapters[]` declaration as you see in the code. The problem is that besides `adapters` storing a pointer to `adapter1`, when it gets printed in `MultiLogicAdapter`, it's another address. I know that I'm passing `adapters` to `MultiLogicAdapter` as a copy, but the copy would have the same references to `adapter1`. So what's happening?

Why I'm iterating through pointers? Because of this: https://www.goinggo.net/2013/09/iterating-over-slices-in-go.html
If I don't, I'll be creating lots of unecessary copies.

Comment: fmt.Printf("Addr: %p\n", adapter1) in first case and fmt.Printf("Addr: %p\n", &adapter) in second. &adapter is pointer to pointer

Comment: To add to @Uvelichitel's comment: The first printf is printing the address of an adapter, the second is printing the address of a local variable containing the address of an adapter.

Comment: @CeriseLimón so when we iterate over something, we're iterating over pointers?

Comment: Range iterates over values from the slice. In the for loop, your code prints the address of one of these values.  You should simply print the value.  `fmt.Printf("Addr: %p\n", adapter)` will give the result you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `var adapters []LogicAdapter`, you have an array of interfaces. The interface is itself essentially an object carrying a pointer to the object you assigned to it (with some extra information to track its type etc.). So when you append an `*ExampleAdapter` to it, you will create an interface instance holding a pointer to an `ExampleAdapter`.

Later, when you do `for _, adapter := range logic.adapters {...}`, the variable `adapter` declared in the loop will be a copy of the interface "object" in the slice. So when you take a pointer to it with `&adapter` you get a pointer to the *interface*, not to the `ExampleAdapter` the interface contains a pointer to.

For a more detailed exposition of the internals of interfaces, see for example https://research.swtch.com/interfaces.