# Passing a []fmt.Stringer parameter to a func

Tags: go

I have a type that implements the stringer interface

```
// RowID stores the ID of a single row in a table
type RowID []string

// String implements Stringer interface for RowID
func (r RowID) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", strings.Join(r, ", "))
}
```

And I have a function that I want to pass a slice of this type (or any other type that implements the Stringer interface) to.

```
// PrintChanges ...
func PrintChanges(ids []fmt.Stringer) {
    for _, id := range ids {
        fmt.Println(id)
    }
}
```

However, The go compiler gives me an error:

```
cannot use rowIDs (type []RowID) as type []fmt.Stringer in argument to PrintChanges
```

I can pass a RowID to a func that accepts a single fmt.Stringer

```
func PrintChange(id fmt.Stringer) {
    fmt.Println(id)
}

...
    PrintChange(RowID{"1", "24"})
```

But for some reason I am not able to pass a slice of RowID to a func that accepts a slice of fmt.Stringer.  What am I missing?

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/io4FPVTBeK6)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/FI8t9xlnp2y

Answer (score 1):

### Keep it simple

It is considered okay by professional Go programmers to repeat functions like this for every type, or to have a for loop over every slice you want to print. This is because Go aims to be as easy to read as possible, i.e. a person who reads a chunk of code for the first time should not be asking questions like "which function overload will this function call go to" (common pitfall in C++, Go does not have function overloads). So you can just write in `main()`:

Playground: https://ideone.com/IL3rGR

```golang
    for _, id := range rowIDs { fmt.Println(id) }
```

Simple and concise.

### Note that `fmt.Println(id)` does not call your `String()` function

This is because the `fmt` library uses the `reflect` library and hardcodes behavior for the `string` type, which you are trying to replace. `RowID` instances are also `string` instances, the library always prefers `string` over its type aliases. I would say it is a bug in the library:

Library source: https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go#L649

```golang
    // Some types can be done without reflection.
    switch f := arg.(type) {
...
    case string:
        p.fmtString(f, verb)
```

### If you really want to

You can use a function that takes an interface{} and makes a runtime reflect type cast to a slice of Stringers. Note that this means you will not see type mismatches during compilation, only in runtime:

Playground: https://ideone.com/vlrBP9

```golang
func castToStringerSlice(iface interface{}) ([]fmt.Stringer, bool /* ok */) {
    if reflect.TypeOf(iface).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return nil, false
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(iface)
    stringers := make([]fmt.Stringer, v.Len())

    for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
        stringers[i] = v.Index(i)
    }

    return stringers, true
}

func PrintChanges(iface_ids interface{}) {
    ids, ok := castToStringerSlice(iface_ids)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal(errors.New("the argument to PrintChanges must be a slice of Stringers"))
    }
    for _, id := range ids {
        fmt.Println(id)
    }
}
```

---

Resources:

- [Go documentation: Why does Go not support overloading of methods and operators?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading)
- [Go documentation: Why does Go not have generic types?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics)
- [Stack Overflow: Express function that takes any slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42987535/11458991)
- [Stack Overflow: Range over interface{} which stores a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026030/11458991)
- [Go documentation: Package reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)