# Why http handler's arguments seem to have their pointer backward?

Tags: go

I am new to go and still trying to figure out a few things.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
}
```

Why is `w` not a pointer and on the other hand `r` is, since the handler function will end up writing into `w` and only read from `r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has already been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255928/249552), but to keep it short.

`w http.ResponseWriter` is actually an interface that's backed by a non-exported pointer.

Whereas `r *http.Request` is an actual exposed struct.

I'd recommend following the above link to learn more why this is.