# Why are pointers used in the callback of http.HandleFunc

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to learn go for web programming. I came across the `http.HandleFunc` function , to which i could provide a callback to handle the web request configured to it.

My small program looks like the following.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var count int
var mu sync.Mutex

func main() {
    var p Point
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "URL.Path =:%q\n", r.URL.Path)
}
```

Why is the *http.Request in the `handler` method a pointer? . I understand that this is how the designed it. But I would like to know why they are mandating a pointer instead of a regular value.

Comment: 1. `http.HandleFunc` is a type, not a function. 2. It doesn't accept a callback. Callbacks are very rare in Go.

Comment: I thought it was actually callback pattern. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since pointer only contains reference, we can use it instead of making a new copy of the request. This way everyone who is working on request struct can see the changes.

There is also good explanation explaining difference between struct and interface. 
[In Go HTTP handlers, why is the ResponseWriter a value but the Request a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255907/in-go-http-handlers-why-is-the-responsewriter-a-value-but-the-request-a-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs a `http.Request` is a quite large & complex struct: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

So for efficiency, a pointer is better than copy-by-value non-pointer.

Also passing a pointer allows any modifications to the struct to persist e.g. [ParseForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm).