# What original type is passed in ServeHTTP's http.ResponseWriter interface?

Tags: http, go, interface

While studying `net/http` I actually wanted to know that how go returns `http.Response` to listener. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255907/in-go-http-handlers-why-is-the-responsewriter-a-value-but-the-request-a-pointer) answer, I found that [http.Response](https://golang.org/src/net/http/response.go) type is passed to ServeHTTP, but that is not the case because on compilation below code throw error. Which means `http.Response` does not implement `http.ResponseWriter` interface. I am curious what is the type which implements `http.ResponseWriter` interface?

```
# command-line-arguments
./server1.go:9:20: http.Response.Header is a field, not a method
./server1.go:9:20: impossible type assertion:
        http.Response does not implement http.ResponseWriter (missing Header method)
```

```golang
func handler(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    actualresp := resp.(http.Response) //https://tour.golang.org/methods/15
    resp.Write([]byte("Hello Web, from go"))
}
func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/api", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: You've misread the answer you linked to. It mentions `http.response`, not `http.Response`. Note the difference of capitalization.

Comment: @RahulPalve to confirm that the *dynamic* type of an interface value is what you expect it to be, you can use the `%T` verb in a `fmt` print. E.g. `fmt.Printf("%T\n", w)` will output `*http.response`.

Comment: Thanks for this tip @mkopriva, Actually this came into my mind but I thought `%T` will print http.`ResponseWriter`.

Comment: Please keep in mind that one of the chief reasons for using an interface is decoupling of the implementation and its clients. So while it might be useful for learning/debugging to find out objects of which concrete type get passed to your handlers, be sure to understand the following: 1) objects of different types might be used when handling requests of different versions of the HTTP protocol (currently there are at least two of them, actively used); 2) this type is free to change in any next Go release—even in minor one—without any warning or mentioning in the release notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http.Response](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response) has the following methods only:

```
func (r *Response) Cookies() []*Cookie
func (r *Response) Location() (*url.URL, error)
func (r *Response) ProtoAtLeast(major, minor int) bool
func (r *Response) Write(w io.Writer) error
```

This does not implement the [http.ResponseWriter](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter) interface which requires:

```
Header() Header
Write([]byte) (int, error)
WriteHeader(statusCode int)
```

So clearly `http.Response` cannot be used as a `http.ResponseWriter`.

Instead, **and as the answer you linked to mentions**, the non-exported [http.response](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/net/http/server.go;l=418) is used. You can find a description of the life of a write on the http server side [in the code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/net/http/server.go;l=1515).

Comment: Thank You, for link to the life of write..